# Idiom: "Хлопот полон рот" or "хлопот полный рот"?

Tags: грамматика, idioms

This idiom roughly translates as "the thing is, he/she is very busy", right?

However, a friend of mine on VK used "Хлопот полный рот", whereas on gramota.ru I saw "хлопот полон рот". Which one is correct, or are they both correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"*Полон*" is the [short form](http://masterrussian.com/aa041601a.shtml) of "*полный*" and in this case they are absolutely interchangeable. However, "*хлопот полон рот*" is more euphonic and thus it is the preferable one.

Answer (score 5):

> This idiom roughly translates as "the thing is, he/she is very busy", right?

Right.

`Хлопот полон рот` is the correct one, but both are perfectly understandable.

Answer (score 2):

**Хлопот полон рот** is idiomatic; **хлопот полный рот** is — well, like saying "shiver my timbers" instead of the more iconic "shiver *me* timbers". **Полон** is a bit of a relic here, from a time when short adjectives were more generally "indefinite", something like the Germanic weak adjective, instead of the more narrow predicative function ("is full") that they have today.